# Java chained constructor calling error

Tags: java

This made me mad (Eclipse Kepler)

```
public class FastReader 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    FastReader a = new FastReader("hi");
}
public FastReader(int a)
{

}
public FastReader(String b)
{
    FastReader(10);
}
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method FastReader(int) is undefined for the type FastReader    
at FastReader.<init>(FastReader.java:14)
at FastReader.main(FastReader.java:6)
```

It almost made me mad! help me get rid of this!
Thank you!

Comment: Use `this(10);` in your second constructor instead

Comment: Google is your friend. Googling for "chain constructors in java" shows the answer as its very first link.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: @JBNizet nowhere in the exception is someone able to deduce that they need to look for "chaining constructors". I think this question is very valid, a duplicate for sure, but valid

Comment: @Isaac I never said the question was invalid. I just said thet, since the OP wants to call a constructor from another constructor in Java, the first thing to do is to do a tiny bit of research by googling, for example "call a constructor from another constructor in Java". Just doing that would have led to the answer immediately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
public FastReader(String b) {
   this(10);
}
```

Comment: You say that my way of calling constructors is completely wrong bro? thanks

Comment: Yes, the compiler is telling you this, the above is the correct syntax for constructor chaining

Answer (score 2):

```
public FastReader(String b)
{
    this(10);
}
```

This is the correct way to call the same class constructor.
If you want to call a same class constructor use the keyword 'this' if you want call the parent class constructor use the keyword 'super'.